# Flutter app deployment to App store rejected with following error -

Tags: flutter, ipad, app-store

### Guideline 2.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata

We were unable to install the app on iPad. The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a way that the app will not install on iOS 13.6.1 .

#### Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key to verify that it contains only the attributes required for your app features or the attributes that must not be present on the device. Attributes specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are required and false if they must not be present on the device.

#### Resources

Please review the Technical Q&A 1397: Understanding the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key for information on the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key.

You may also wish to review the dictionary keys table in the "Declaring the Required Device Capabilities" section of the App Programming Guide for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following solved this issue in the info.plist:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use this code in info.plist

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
<string>camera-flash</string>
</array>
```

Comment: And what does this answer to? You do this if you need the camera, right. But that's not necessarily the case. The actual problem is that the App Store process is ready to issue this warning even if there is no `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` at all.